# ASP.NET Core 2.1 CookieAuthentication session timeout

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

Session times out before CookieAuthentication cookie does, trying to simulate "Remember Me" functionality when authenticating against a remote JWT-based API.

### Rough overview

App #1 - .Net Core 2.0.8 - using Identity and JWT tokens (Angular app with .net core & ef core API)

App #2 - .Net Core 2.1.1 - using CookieAuthentication Scheme to login clients, calling the `App #1` API to authenticate / validate credentials.  The token is retrieved and saved for future api calls (to get further user details, to update user details, etc)

The code in App #1 works fine and expiration of the token / refresh token works as expected (tested independently using Postman) - I added a parameter to send with the authentication call to set the token expiration, so I can set it to 5mins or 30 days, for example.

In App #2, I have in startup:

```
        services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = "host:port";
        });

        var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("host:port");

        services
            .AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToRedis(redis, $"{appSettings.RedisInstanceName}-DataProtection-Keys")
            .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(30))

        services.AddSession(opts =>
        {
            opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            opts.Cookie.Name = ".session";
            opts.IdleTimeout = exp;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(opts =>
            {
                opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                opts.Cookie.Name = ".session.auth";
            });
```

In the above, exp is set to 240 minutes, i.e. 4 hours - as a test.

When the login happens, I do:

- Call remote api with username/password to authenticate, on success receive access token
- Store access token in local session, together with basic user identity (firstname, lastname, email, user ID)
- call identity SignIn to set authenticated status so that I can use [Authorize] no controllers / actions.

  ```
      var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
      {
          AllowRefresh = true,
          ExpiresUtc = exp,
          IsPersistent = rememberMe,
          IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
          RedirectUri = null
      };

      await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
          CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
          new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
          authProperties
      );
  ```

(exp is the same as above, 240 minutes)

So the intended functionality here is if "rememberMe" is true, the cookie and session is alive for up to 4 idle hours.  In the real world, this will probably be an extended period, i.e. 30 days.  If "rememberMe" is false, it should last for the session only with IdleTimeout of the default 20 mins or whatever.

The question is, how do I align the Authentication cookie with the normal application cookie that controls stuff saved against the session? i.e. `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<T>("key");`

What happens now, is the application session will expire but the authentication doesn't, but with the remote api's access token saved in the session, it's lost, so I can't refresh that information and can't make any further API calls.  OR, how do I save info against the authenticated session?

Is this a bad way / what would be a better way for this use case against an API?

Comment: Session and auth are independent. More to the point, session uses sliding expiration, whereas auth uses absolute expiration. As a result, attempts to align the two are futile. What you *should* be doing is adding this information as claims on your user principal, instead of in the session.

Comment: @ChrisPratt makes sense, I was wondering if I can do that as I haven't done "Identity" with .net before.  If I have the token as a claim, I can refresh the user info in the session whenever needed....

Comment: You can refresh the claims too, which is actually a more direct route. The docs cover all this.